# Definite Integral with variable limit

Tags: calculus

$$\int\limits_0^{x^2} \sqrt{t} e^{-t} dt$$
I think i have to use gamma function but the upper limit needs to be infinity so i could not did so , how can i figure out this problem with gamma function or any other way

Comment: Try $t=y^2$ and one integration by parts will lead you to something quite well known.

Comment: It leads to the following integral 
$$\int\limits_0^{x^2} e^{-y^2} dy$$

Comment: On the other hand, if the complete question actually is $$\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_0^{x^2} \sqrt{t} e^{-t} dt$$ then no erf or probility function is required.

Answer (score 2):

Using integration by parts leads to

$$\int\limits_0^{x^2}\sqrt{t} \,e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t=-\sqrt{x^2} \,e^{-x^2}+\int\limits_0^{x^2}\frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{t}} \,e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$$

If we apply the substitution $\sqrt{t}=u$ we get

$$\int\limits_0^{x^2}\sqrt{t} \,e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t=-\sqrt{x^2} \,e^{-x^2}+\int\limits_0^{x}e^{-u^2} \mathrm{d}u$$

The last integral is the definition of the error function and we finally have
$$\int\limits_0^{x^2}\sqrt{t} \,e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t=-x \,e^{-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{\pi}\,\mathrm{erf}(x)$$

with $x=\sqrt{x^2}$.